# Cannot import the library while the installation was successful

Tags: python, audio, installation, google-colaboratory, scikits

I am using Google Colab to write some codes. I need to use scikits.audiolab. Even though the installation seems to be successful, I am not able to import it.

Does someone know why it happens and how can I solve?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`scikits.audiolab` is a very old package (the [last release](https://pypi.org/project/scikits.audiolab/#history) was in 2010) and it does not work with Python 3.

After switching to a Python 2 runtime (*Runtime->Change runtime type* and select *Python 2*), I was able to install it without the `--local` flag and import it:

```
!pip install scikits.audiolab
import scikits.audiolab
```